# Google Tag Manager - Invalid Input

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

every time i try to publish a container through Google Tag manager, I keep getting this error "**Invalid input. You may have stale data; refresh the page and try again**".

I have tried restarting the browser but even this hasn't helped. Any idea why this is happening ? Is there an issue with the new release of GTM or is this is a common issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have some add block browser extentions or other extentions that block GTM

Comment: Nope that doesnt seems to be the case.. I had AdBlock i tried disabling and publishing the container again.. but still the same result

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Have tried with firefox, chrome, incognito chrome and private session firefox as well

Comment: Did you try on other PC?

Comment: Yes. I hate adblocker from now.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your existing browser tab, then try again in the original tab.